# Counting with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm having a program in Spark Streaming that detects incoming files in HDFS, what I want to do is analyse each file and test the existence of two words inside each file, and at each point know how many files contain those two words. 
What I tried to do is :

```
val recherche1 = lines.map(x => (x.split(":")(0),x.split(":")(1))).filter(x => x._2 == "mot1")
    val recherche2 = lines.map(x => (x.split(":")(0),x.split(":")(1))).filter(x => x._2 == "mot2")
    val n1 = recherche1.count()
    val n2 = recherche1.count()
   val p = n1.foreachRDD(rdd => {cont1 = rdd.count()
    if (cont1 > 0)
    {n2.foreachRDD(rdd => {cont2 = rdd.count()
      if (cont2 > 0)
      {number = number + 1}
      else
      {number = number}
    })}
    })
```

what I want is to use the value of the variable "number" so since I can't print it in Spark Streaming, I try to put it inside HBase, unfortunately it doesn't work and when I launch the script in spark-submit, it returns the error:

```
adding new inputs transformations and output operations after starting a context is not supported
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or could tell me how to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the reason of that error is that some `DStream` operation is called after you call `streamingContext.start`, hence the problem must be outside the scope of the code snippet shown here.

Comment: A side comment to the problem: It should be possible to avoid doing the mapping over the input twice to find the two words. Let's first get past the current error and then think about optimizing this process.

Comment: @maasg when I delete this snippet of code, the error disappears that's why I assumed that it's the cause of the problem

Comment: Move this code before the start of the streaming context.

Comment: that's what I do : 

ssc.start() 
ssc.awaitTermination()

are always at the end of the script

Comment: @maasg could there be any other cause ?

Comment: no. could you post the entire code? including the part where the streamingContext is created and started?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the whole structure of the code shown in the question by the answer of my question : [filter the lines by two words Spark Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650184/filter-the-lines-by-two-words-spark-streaming) and it worked, maybe this structure is not suitable for Spark Streaming ..