# filter the lines by two words Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there a way to filter with one expression the lines containing a word "word1" or the other "word2"
something like :

```
val res = lines.filter(line => line.contains("word1" or "word2"))
```

because this expression doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If line is a `String` optimal choice would regexp:

```
val pattern = "word1|word2".r

lines.filter(line => pattern.findFirstIn(line).isDefined)
```

otherwise (other sequence type) you can use [`Seq.exists`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@exists%28p:A=%3EBoolean%29:Boolean):

```
lines.filter(line => Seq("foo", "bar").exists(s => line.contains(s)))
```

which takes a single which maps from element to boolean (here `(String) ⇒ Boolean`) and:

> tests whether a predicate holds for at least one element of this iterable collection.